# How can I configure an ASP.NET MVC Core 6 web app to use two different Azure AD tenants as authentication authorities?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, openid

I have an ASP.NET MVC Core 6 web app that is hosted on an on-premises server. We have two different Azure tenants. It is straightforward enough to add authentication to a single tenant to allow users to login to the web app. I have a new requirement to allow users from another tenant to also login to the app. How can I add in two Azure AD authorities?

I have seen some samples on how to add multiple authentication authorities, but they are always different ones (login with Azure and login with Google, for example) and not two Azure.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317118/14973743 ?

Comment: Yes, but I understand this enables the app to be available to any tenant. I have to have the app only available to the two specific tenants. Also, one tenant is in the Government Cloud of Azure, so the auth URL endpoint is different.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add two AddOpenIDConnect handlers, give them different names

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc1", options => { });
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc2", options => { });
```

Then give each one different callback paths, like:

```
options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc1";
options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc2";
```

and as well

```
SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc1";
SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc2";
```

That is a good starting point. Then you use one of the following to choose how the user should authenticate.

```
HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc1");
HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc2");
```

If you have samesite cookie issues, or cookie issues in general, then you can in chrome, for a given request, see if there are any cookie issues under the cookies tab, as shown below:

[image]

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks. I get an error that the redirect URI does not match. It seems the authentication response from Azure always wants to use the default /signin-oidc, even though I don't use that (I have set /signin-oidc1 and 2, as you indicated).

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I haven't tried specifically with AzureAD, but I assumed you could customize it. Don't see the reason why you can't change it. The issue that both can't listen to the same URL. either you need two different domains or ports for the redirectURL?

Comment: If I add /signin-oidc in Azure AD as a Redirect URI, it does go back to the application, but attempts to go to the default /Account/Login endpoint and gets stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: If you end up in a redirect loop, then it sounds like a cookie problem, try to make sure the samesite attribute is set to none and that you use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. We do use HTTPS and set the samesite attribute.

Comment: Does it still not work? and samesite is set to none?

Comment: Maybe we don't set the samesite correctly? What are you suggesting it be set to and how?

Comment: You can use a tool like https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler to inspect the request and see if the cookies are included in the requests from the browser, or see my updated answer how you can detect cookie issues in the browser (chrome)